# MongoSocketOpenException in Spring-Boot Application

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-network

I'm trying to run my app on Docker. Problem is that when I'm running image of `mongo`, it works perfectly. But then I'm running myapp image which using `mongo` as a db, it gives `com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket`. By the way I'm creating both of them under the same network.

Exception

[image]

Note: when I run myapp from my local it works perfectly. Problem is just about image of my app. I can`t understand what is difference? Why dos it give this error?

First command, that run mongo image:

```
docker run --name=mongo --rm --network=mynet  -p 27017:27017 mongo
```

Second command, that run myapp image:

```
docker run --name=myapp --rm --network=mynet  -p 8088:8080 -e MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017 myapp
```

Inspection of mynet network:

```
"Name":"enote",
"Id":"95c6704778676fded0f856b2f905d60544bf67a83910b96193f00ef6a23730be",
"Created":"2023-08-21T07:59:34.479354749Z",
"Scope":"local",
"Driver":"bridge",
"EnableIPv6":false,
"IPAM":{
   "Driver":"default",
   "Options":{
      
   },
   "Config":[
      {
         "Subnet":"172.22.0.0/16",
         "Gateway":"172.22.0.1"
      }
   ]
},
"Internal":false,
"Attachable":false,
"Ingress":false,
"ConfigFrom":{
   "Network":""
},
"ConfigOnly":false,
"Containers":{
   "bf1bd274fcfdd61f93afc8be87d3542f1cefe81d62587a3d669b09b06cef2e84":{
      "Name":"enote-java",
      "EndpointID":"af36329326a5ce2c0ac3b24d1dc60c63d27a22e2df2b50c5469094bae21b8a05",
      "MacAddress":"02:42:ac:16:00:03",
      "IPv4Address":"172.22.0.3/16",
      "IPv6Address":""
   },
   "fa44ba0e009744610ec7f93ff7c04078692d853714193e2dc542cfe2ed815845":{
      "Name":"mongo",
      "EndpointID":"89be69458e5614976622731e89351f93cd406f8f1dfdc474480310039b8c4a74",
      "MacAddress":"02:42:ac:16:00:02",
      "IPv4Address":"172.22.0.2/16",
      "IPv6Address":""
   }
},
"Options":{
   
},
"Labels":{
   
}
```

Dockerfile of myapp:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jdk-11.0.2.9-slim
WORKDIR /opt
ENV PORT 8080
EXPOSE 8080
COPY target/*.jar /opt/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT exec java -jar app.jar
```

Comment: Since you are using [tag:spring-boot], I would expect properties like `SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_HOST=mongo` and `SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_PORT=27017` or an `application.yml`. In the example you provided I don't see an `application.yml` copied into the docker image, nor a `docker run` command with these environment variables. Could you clarify how you set your environment variables when you run locally? It's not clear what `MONGO_URL` means.

Comment: @WLefever thanks for your comment. this is my application props for `mongodb` when i run locally: `spring.data.mongodb.uri=${MONGO_URL:mongodb://localhost:27017/dev}` . `MONGO_URL` sets an environment variable inside the container. `mongo` is precisely the name that I gave to the MongoDB container with the `--name=mongo` flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configurations solved my issue -

docker-compose:

`version: '3.1' services: mongodb: image: mongo container_name: "mongodb" ports: - '27017:27017' networks: - myapp myapp: image: myuser/myapp:1.0.0 environment: - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017/dev container_name: "myapp" ports: - "8080:8080" depends_on: - mongodb networks: - myapp networks: myapp:`

.properties:

`spring.data.mongodb.uri=${MONGO_URL:mongodb://mongodb:27017/dev}`